# Probability of obtaining two pairs from $5$ cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Question: Given a poker deck of $52$ cards. Find the probability of getting hand two pairs among $5$ cards chosen.

My calculation is as follows:
$$\frac{52}{52} \times \frac{3}{51}\times \frac{48}{50} \times \frac{3}{49}\times \frac{44}{48}.$$
My logic is as follows: 
I calculate the probability of getting $5$ cards such that first $2$ cards form a pair and subsequent $2$ cards also form a pair. Last card can be anything except the number used in first $2$ pairs.

Therefore, for first card, we pick any card. So it has probability $1$.

For second card, we must pick the same number as the previous card. So, it has probability of $\frac{3}{51}.$

Similarly, for third card, we can pick any card except the number in first pair. So, it has probability of $\frac{48}{50}.$

For fourth card, we need to pick the same number as third card. So, it has probability of $\frac{3}{49}.$

For the fifth card, we mustn't chose the two numbers used in the first $2$ pairs. So, it has probability $\frac{44}{48}.$

However, I couldn't figure out the number of possible such sequences.

After comparing to answer found online, it seems that I am missing a factor of $15.$ 
But I do not know how to obtain $15.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of $5$-tuples that contain $2$ letters $a$, $2$ letters $b$ and $1$ letter $c$ equals:$$\frac{5!}{2!2!1!}=30$$

But also in your case there is no essential distinction between e.g. $(a,a,b,b,c)$ and $(b,b,a,a,c)$ where $2$ pairs are switched, so that we need another factor $2$ to repair:$$\frac12\frac{5!}{2!2!1!}=15$$

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation insists that the first pair be the first two cards you draw and the second pair be the third and fourth cards you draw.  You have not counted hands like $A23A2$.  You have also counted $AA223$ and $22AA3$ separately.  There are exactly $\frac 12$ as many unordered combinations as you computed because the order of the pairs can be switched.  Then given an unordered combination there are $\frac {5!}{2!\cdot 2!}=30$ ways to put them in order, so the probability is $15$ times higher than what you got.